# Prior Probabilities vs Sampling

Tags: sampling, sas, sample

In case i have a dataset which has 100000 records and only 10000 of them represent Churn cases. Hence before building a predictive model i set a prior probability as 10% for CHURN and 90% for NON CHURN.

My question is will this take care of oversampling issue or should i explicitly create a sample and have equal proportion of CHURN and NON CHURN cases and then set up a prior probability on this dataset

Thanks,
Sachi